# How to to get node value?

Tags: java, android

How to get userid value in Java on Android in this example?

```xml
<RESPONSE>
    <SINGLE>
        <KEY name="sitename"></KEY>
        <KEY name="username"></KEY>
        <KEY name="firstname"></KEY>
        <KEY name="lastname"></KEY>
        <KEY name="fullname"></KEY>
        <KEY name="lang"></KEY>
        <KEY name="userid"></KEY>
        <KEY name="siteurl"></KEY>
        <KEY name="userpictureurl"></KEY>
        <KEY name="functions"></KEY>
        <KEY name="downloadfiles"></KEY>
        <KEY name="release"></KEY>
        <KEY name="version"></KEY>
        <KEY name="mobilecssurl"></KEY>
    </SINGLE>
</RESPONSE>
```

Require output

```
[userid value]
```

Comment: <KEY name="userid"></KEY> Key attribute name!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SAX you can get node value:

```
    String xPathExpression = "RESPONSE/SINGLE/KEY[@name= 'userid']/text()";
    XPath path = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String result = (String) path.evaluate(xPathExpression, new InputSource(new FileReader("..path to xml file..")), XPathConstants.STRING);
```